# cron rsnapshot - weekly before monthly how to

Tags: cron, rsync, backup, rsnapshot

I'm trying to run `rsnapshot` per the doc specs, to avoid race conditions.  basically the [docs](http://rsnapshot.org/rsnapshot/docs/docbook/rest.html#automation) say to run the largest interval before the smaller one, about a half hour apart, and so forth.  (**not using sync_first**)

So, I run `monthly` at 1:15am on the 1st of each month, `weekly` at 1:45am Mondays, `daily` at 2:15am, and `hourly` at 2:45am (every 4 hours, besides the point, the important thing is that the 2:45 am is ran after `daily` is done.)

I want to run this successfully, **without sync_first**  to get all the directories populated correctly.  As it stands now, its fubar'ing at the `weekly`/`monthly`.  the `daily`'s and `hourly`'s are normally working fine.

Its important for the user to know that when the `hourly` runs, this is the *actual file copy*, that `sync_first` would otherwise do, so the `hourly` needs to be run initially for the files to be there in the first place.  Everything else is just a symlink copied up, unless there is a file change.  Don't be confused by this, just know that `hourly` is the file copier.

Its also important for the user to know that the higher interval jobs knock off a directory from its lower interval, causing the lower interval to now be ran to create the new one.  E.g. when `monthly` is ran, it knocks off the 4th `weekly`(actually named weekly.3 since they start at 0), then weekly needs to be ran again to get it back to 4 weeks worth, or does it?  Is this my misconception, or is this my problem?

As mentioned, in cron `monthly` runs at 1st day of month, `weekly` runs on Mondays.

**Question**

Do I need to run this `weekly` just after the `monthly`, on the same day, ~30 mins after the `monthly` runs to refill that missing `weekly` directory, or should i just wait until the `weekly`'s normal day? (Monday)

The issue I can see is if I don't schedule the `monthly` to run on a certain day of the week (the exact day the `weekly` is running on), then when the `monthly` runs again, the `daily`, then `hourly` follows correctly, but since the 1st of the month isn't always on a Monday, the `weekly` isn't running right after the `monthly`, leaving a hole in the backups (a missing `week` dir).

There is a [partial solution](https://sysadminspot.com/linux/cron-to-run-on-first-specified-day-of-the-month/) to get monthly to run on a specific day, but I'm trying to avoid this cron hack. I don't recall having an issue before on this, I'm not sure why I can't get it to flow properly now, MAYBE its fine like this?  I wonder if there's no issue that weekly won't run just after monthly since the previously `weekly`'s will still be there??

Comment: Still waiting on a clear answer on this please.  Which is the definitive order in cron to do this?